# What's causing this error in SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer, error-message

In the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), how come:

- `select sum(len(body)) from posts` works fine, *but,*
- `select sum(len(text)) from comments` throws an error?

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

I experimented and discovered if I `CAST..as BigInt` it will work (on either of the above queries), and that comparable field in the same table `select sum(len(userdisplayname))` works fine with out conversion.

```
Posts.body                nvarchar(max)    43,016,689,192 characters   Works
Comments.Text             nvarchar(600)     9,711,438,180 characters   Errors
Comments.UserDisplayName  nvarchar(30)          7,616,503 characters   Works

                                T-SQL Int: ±4,294,967,295
                 T-SQL BigInt: ±9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

`Post.Body` is much larger, and `Comments.UserDisplayName` is declared similarly as `Comments.Text`, so I don't understand the difference.

Is this a SQL-thing or an SEDE-thing?

([example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/873481))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a T-SQL thingy, see the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) about `len`:

> #### Return Types
>
> **bigint** if *expression* is of the **varchar(max)**, **nvarchar(max)** or **varbinary(max)** data types; otherwise, **int**.

So the `Posts.Body` query knows it needs to sum `len(varchar(max))`, a `bigint` and doesn't overflow (43 billion is not enough for that), while the `Comments.Text` query tries to sum `len(varchar(600))` which is an `int` variable and does overflow (9.7 billion is larger than 2.1 billion, the maximum for an `int`). The `sum` on `Comments.UserDisplayName` isn't simply large enough to overflow an `int` variable.

Comment: I was about to say you must have my issue backwards, until I read your answer a couple more times.  So presumably, the `len` function needs to store it's result in a temp variable while it calculates - for which it needs to "assume" a datatype - which it's guessing correctly for the `bigint`, but it's not expecting an `nchar(600)` to exceed `int`'s signed max of 4.3billion, so I need to be explicit with that one...  (or that's how ***I*** will remember it even if it's not quite right!)   Good answer, short and sweet, thanks!

Comment: I guess this also explains something semi-related was wondering... correct me if I'm wrong, but `T-SQL` integers are ***signed (always)*** while MySQL integers are **unsigned *by default*** unless declared as `SIGNED` ... so, in SEDE anything larger than ~+2.1 Billion needs to be an `bigint`.  Right?

Comment: Yes, they are always signed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 (except for tinyint, which ranges from 0 to 255). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4451967/4751173